# Re-rendering backbone.js views on resize?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have two views here, their structure relies on `$(window).height()`. So when I re-size the browser or mess with the console, I need the height to be calculated. The below works for me, but I haven't seen any one mention doing it like this.

So I want to know if this code is awful or okay or great. Obviously all I am doing is telling my program when to instantiate my views.

```
// Play
$(document).ready(function() {
    intro = new App.Views.Intro();
    flight = new App.Views.Flight();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    intro = new App.Views.Intro();
    flight = new App.Views.Flight();
});
```

Not sure if this fits the guidelines, but I do not want this to come back to hurt me later on.

**Edit:** Not sure why I didn't think of this, but below seems pretty practical. The reason I didn't want to re-render inside the view is because it seems I would have to add a `remove()` method and "bind" the resize. Not very pretty and organized if you ask me. example [How do I add a resize event to the window in a view using Backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110060/how-do-i-add-a-resize-event-to-the-window-in-a-view-using-backbone)

```
// Play
$(document).ready(function() {
    intro = new App.Views.Intro();
    flight = new App.Views.Flight();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    intro.render();
    flight.render();    
});
```

Comment: Do you have a `.render()` method in your views that you can call instead? If they do extra things, perhaps you can refactor out the formatting-specific code into a `.layout()` function or something, and then simply call it from your resize handler.

Comment: Yeah I do have a `.render()` method, I call `this.render()` in the `initialize()` method, then inside the `render()` I say `this.$el.height($(window).height())` or add a css property. So by re instantiating on re-size, I am re-rendering. I just want to build a great thing and don't want bad practice to be around.

Comment: so instead of re-instantiating it you're saying do something like `intro.layout()`

Comment: Oh yeah so I did `intro.render();` `flight.render();` and that worked good. This seems better.

Comment: Yep, or if it won't cause any unwanted side effects, you could also just do `intro.render()`.

Comment: yeah I hear you there, as of now it won't, its a SUPER fresh project and the code is minuscule, so if it does become a prob ill just move the logic of layout into another method.

Comment: The idea behind this is to have an `.intro` div which is the height of the window, then the content below it to have either `margin-top` or `top` the same pixel value as the window height so it's pushed off the screen, then when user scrolls the div that was pushed off scrolls over the `.intro` div for a cool scrolling effect. I figured I'd take all the time I learned backbone.js and apply it to this website. It also keeps all my elements organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base view class to encapsulate this behavior. This can be useful for a few reasons. One benefit is you can separate the `resize` behavior from the `render` code. Sometimes `render` does alot more work, such as serializing a model and rewriting large parts of the dom, which you don't want to re-run.

Here [is a pen demonstrating a pattern](http://codepen.io/somethingkindawierd/pen/uLvyn) I've used so that after the initial render only the width/height are adjusted and you don't need to re-render any of the views simply to resize them. The code is copied below for convenience.

This is just a sample. In a real app where I might be resizing a few views I typically refactor the `window.resize` event out so I only wire up one listener.

```
var ResizeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: '#view-tpl',

  initialize: function() {
    $(window).on('resize.resizeview', this.onResize.bind(this));
  },

  remove: function() {
    $(window).off('resize.resizeview');
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
  },

  render: function () {
    var $tmpl = $(this.template);
    var tmpl = _.template($tmpl.html());
    this.$el.append(tmpl());
    this.onResize();
    return this;
  },

  onResize: function () {
    var w = $(window).width()
      , h = $(window).height();
    console.log('resize', w, h);
    this.resize(w, h);
  },

  resize: function (w, h) {
    this.$el.css({
      'width': w,
      'height': h
    });
  }
});

var view = new ResizeView();
$('body').append(view.render().$el);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for taking the time, I gotta save this because as the code becomes more complex or should I say when there is more added onto the code I am sure this will come in handy. Based on what I read, yes this is the right way to do it, but for now it's more than I need I think. Good snippet to revert to though thanks.

Comment: Green check because this is the proper way to do it, I am not personally using it as of now, if someone comes across this, then this is a good answer.